# 'FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.h' file not found' when using Product -> Archive

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase

I am having a problem when I try Product -> Archive on my xcode project. I get error messages:

```
'FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.h' file not found
Could not build Objective-C module 'Firebase'
```

This error only occurs when I do Product -> Archive using Generic iOS Device as my device, not when running simulator on a real device.

I have looked for answers elsewhere on the internet, but no solution I have found has worked.

As in this [link](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/1166) Reverting Firebase to version 4.13.0 in my podfile does not work for me. Commenting out `use frameworks` is not good for me; I need it for other pods.

This [link](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/2233) suggests that I do:

close Xcode, 
`rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/`, 
`pod deintegrate`, 
`pod install`, 
restart Xcode

However, that does not work either.

One [link](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/1977) suggests that I unlink react-native-firebase by adding this to the end of my podfile:

```
post_install do |installer|
  system("mkdir -p Pods/Headers/Public/FirebaseCore && cp Pods/FirebaseCore/Firebase/Core/Public/* Pods/Headers/Public/FirebaseCore/")
end
```

But that just shifts the error message to `No such module 'Alamofire'`. Using that I can not get Product -> Archive to recognize Alamofire.

Here is my podfile for reference:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '11.3'

target 'Spotbirdparking' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Spotbirdparking
  pod 'Stripe'
  pod 'Alamofire'
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod 'Firebase/Storage', '~> 5.0'
  pod 'Firebase/Database'
  pod 'SDWebImage'
  pod 'GoogleMaps'
  pod 'GooglePlacePicker'
  pod 'GooglePlaces'
  pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift', '~> 5.0'
  pod 'JTAppleCalendar', '~> 7.0' 
  pod 'MBProgressHUD'
  pod 'themis'

  target 'SpotbirdparkingTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

I am very stuck with this, have been looking at it for days. Would really appreciate any help.

Comment: have you read this? https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/1166. My guess would be that its related to `use_frameworks!`, as its said "Comment the next line if you're not using Swift"

Comment: Read that, it is the first link that I referenced, I can not comment `use_frameworks`

Comment: Take a look at the current pods [Firebase Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#available-pods). Also, ensure your cocoapods is updated to 1.10.1 or later `pod --version`

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and spend quite some time trying to solving it.
For me solution was to reduce amount of available architectures. Somehow when I rolled back to Firebase version 4.13 xcode returned error that one of my pod do not support arm7 architecture.

In project target settings for Valid architectures field I left only arm64 and arm64e architectures and project successfully archived for **Generic IOS device**

My Podfile

```html
source 'https://cdn.cocoapods.org/'
platform :ios, '11.0'
inhibit_all_warnings!
use_frameworks!

target 'XXX' do
  
  pod 'Fabric', '~> 1.7'
  pod 'Crashlytics', '~> 3.10'
  pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.5'
  pod 'SwiftHEXColors', '~> 1.2'
  pod 'KeychainSwift', '~> 10.0'
  pod 'SkyFloatingLabelTextField', '~> 3.6'
  pod 'Anyline', '16'
  pod 'TwilioVideo', '3.2'
  pod 'Firebase/Core'

  abstract_target 'Tests' do
    target "XXXUnitTests"

      pod 'Quick'
      pod 'Nimble'
    end
end
```

[image]